# How to convert vector of tuples to JSON objects?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am creating a REST API in rocket.rs and have a function that returns a vector of tuples that I need to return to the web frontend. The vector is of the form `[(1, "abc"), (2, "mno"), (3, "xyz")]`.

I need to be send out as a JSON list form `[{"score": 1, "text": "abc"}, {"score": 2, "text": "mno"}, {"score": 3, "text": "xyz"}]`.

How do I do that in Rust? I tested it using `serde` as

```
let my_list: Vec<(i32, String)> = vec![
    (1, "abc".to_string()),
    (2, "feg".to_string()),
    (3, "xyz".to_string()),
];
let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&my_list).unwrap();

println!("serialized = {}", serialized);
```

I would need a way to create the key, value pairs and convert. What is the way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using tuples? If your tuple fields have "semantic" names you should consider a struct instead, which should also solve your serialization issue:

```
#[derive(Clone,PartialEq,Eq,PartialOrd,Ord,Hash,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize)]
struct Entry {
    pub score: i32,
    pub text: String,
}
```

Comment: The function that uses the tuples was from another rust project. But I asked the author of that to change it into struct and it worked. Thanks !

Comment: @Shepmaster Please consider not editing minor whitespace "issues", see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263120/1478356 - I'd like to keep them my way (no spaces in `derive(..)` and `use {...}`).

Comment: @Stefan Everyone is entitled to their own style of course, but I edit *every* question and answer to the current accepted Rust style as determined by running `rustfmt`. This allows every future reader of a Q&A to not have to deal with an arbitrary posters chosen style. I encourage you to adopt the community standards and perhaps participate in setting them.

Comment: @Shepmaster I think those edits are considered "not ok" by the stackoverflow community, and I think you know it. How about you adopt the edit rules of the community, and perhaps participate in setting them? Maybe the community is open to reconsider style edits when a formatting tool is available.

Comment: @Stefan you are always welcome to rollback your code, as you have. I will continue editing Q&A to adhere to the Rust style guide as part of my normal editing (e.g. grammar, typos, formatting, providing complete error messages, etc.) and upvoting Q&A that meet those conditions. I completely and honestly believe that my edits (1) do not harm anyone and (2) make the overall state of Stack Overflow better for  people searching for Rust Q&A. You are welcome to submit me to the Meta tribunal or flag my comments / edits for a moderator if you truly believe I am harming the community.

Comment: And, before I forget, I apologize for offending you via my edits, that was not my intention.

Comment: No offense taken, and I appreciate the work you do most of the time :) Not sure I want to escalate this; but please consider that many people find it rude if you edit code they wrote just to make it look the way you like it (even if you're backed by a code formatting tool), which is the part that imho harms the community.

Comment: *consider that many people find it rude if you edit* — yes, I am unfortunately aware of this; I've had multiple people threaten to quit Stack Overflow because I've corrected something in their post (spelling, grammar, formatting, indentation). *the way you like it* — who said that **I** like everything that rustfmt does? *harms the community* —  perhaps it does harm a subset of the community of people who ask and answer questions; I'm concerning myself with helping every single person who comes to a Q&A from a search engine and doesn't want to learn a new Rust format just to get an answer.